# Getting " Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'div' " even after importing Common Module - Angular 9

Tags: angular

I keep getting that error. I am importing the Common Module as well as declaring the component in my module! Please let me know what is wrong with it. ngif works fine on the components imported in the App Module. For some reason it does not work for this one. This module is being lazy loaded in the app routing module by the way.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { EnterpriseRoutingModule } from './enterprise-routing.module';
import { LandingComponent } from './pages/landing/landing.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [LandingComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    EnterpriseRoutingModule
  ],
})
export class EnterpriseModule { }
```

Routing Module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { LandingComponent } from './pages/landing/landing.component';


const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: LandingComponent,
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class EnterpriseRoutingModule { }
```

Here is the HTML

```
<div class="row" *ngIf="true">
          <div class="col-lg-6">
            <h1>
              Feature Heading 1
            </h1>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
              eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut
              enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
              nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
              reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat
              nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident,
              sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-6">
            img
          </div>
        </div>
```

It's set equal to true so I could test, but obviously not working.

**Update**: Not sure what I did, but I went to bed, woke up and it worked, didn't change a single line of code.

Comment: What do you mean by common module?

Comment: Did you find the solution? I am also importing CommonModule in my modile, and am getting this error.

Answer (score 2):

Try restarting your `ng serve` command . It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try importing BrowserModule.

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
 @NgModule({
     imports: [BrowserModule ]
  })
```

Comment: This won't work. It throws an error. I am already importing this in the app.module.ts file. The above module is a feature module

Answer (score 0):

wow, that was the Solution
In my Case:

```
 path: 'pop-object',
loadChildren: () => import('./pages/pop-object/pop-object.module').then( m => m.PopObjectPageModule),
canLoad: [LoginGuard],
```

removed then LoginGuard and it worked

Answer (score -2):

I managed to solve this problem by removing the route guard from the component in the route module, which in my case was a modal.