# Angular throws error: can't bind to "ngIf" since it isn't a known property of "ng-container"

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

I am making a project migration from Angular 7 to 11, and one particular module renders with this error:

```
Can't bind to "ngIf" since it isn't a known property of "ng-container"
```

I have `CommonModule` imported for the module, and previously module worked with Angular 7.

To load the component I use routing, and it seems to be working fine as ngOnInit executes API call based on router `:id`.

Any thoughts?

UPD
I didn't specify that my component which causes errors was loaded as I direct route like `{path: 'some-path', component: SomeComponent}` in the parent module. I changed it to lazy loading approach and it works now. Not sure what caused errors and why it worked in the 7th version.

Comment: post your code here

Comment: @Sajeetharan I can't. Please rely on my description

Comment: I assume you need to replace `ng-if` with `*ngIf`

Comment: can you please post your code of your AppModule ?

Comment: @pbachman AppModule loads routing module which has a route to the component I mentioned

Comment: @EugeneMescheryakov the thing is you have to import BrowserModule in your AppModule and in all other Modules you have to import CommonModule, then it should work.

Comment: @pbachman I have it as well. There are plenty of modules and components which work

Comment: check [Getting “ Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'div'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60897702/getting-cant-bind-to-ngif-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-div-even-a)

Answer (score 2):

You should use `*ngIf="condition"` instead of `ng-If="condition"`

With **CommonModule** imported a working solution should look like:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="condtition">TEST</ng-container>
```

https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf

Please make sure **BrowserModule** and **BrowserAnimationsModule** is imported only once (normally in **appModule**). All other modules should import **CommonModule**.

Comment: Please post your Module (imports) and code. That piece is a test from my project and it works fine. Your error is not related to *ngIf, something else is going wrong then.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you imported common module

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule
    ]
})
```

and in angular you need to use `*ngIf` rather than `ng-if`(it is for angularjs)

Comment: he already mention that the CommonModule is imported.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have written it wrong.. It should be ***ngIf** instead of ng-if

Comment: I made a mistake rewriting the error. Its "ngIf" in the error message, in the code I have *ngIf